# Javascript : generate random number function and push into array

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to push a random number of bunnies into a canvas from 1~10 in Javascript.
However, the `Math.random()` method doesn't seem to be working. It just gives me one bunny. What am I doing wrong?

```
var field = [];

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

field.push(randomNum * new Bunny());

function Bunny() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't give you any bunnies at all. `randomNum * new Bunny()` will be `NaN`<sup>1</sup>, because you're trying to multiply an object with a number.

If you want multiple bunnies, you have to create them, probably in a loop:

```
var field = [];

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
for (var n = 0; n < randomNum; ++n) {          // Loop
    field.push(new Bunny());                   // creating and pushing
}                                              // multiple bunnies

function Bunny() {
// ...
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Or a number, if you've overridden `valueOf` on `Bunny.prototype`, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I think you should use `1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)`

Comment: @mortezaT: Indeed, if the goal is to have between 1 and 10 bunnies (inclusive), yes, we'd want the `+1`. If the goal is to have between 0 and 9 bunnies (inclusive), then we wouldn't.

Comment: @AmyChun: See mortezaT's comment above, you likely want `+1` on the line generating the random number.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Yes, I've noticed that during updating my code. Thanks for the tip, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
var field = [];

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

for (k=0; k<randomNum; k++)

{

field.push(new Bunny());

}
```